# Typescript, redux: how to get type from angle bracket?

Tags: typescript, redux

Suppose we have:

```
type reducerType = Reducer<{user: string;}>
type reducedType = ???  // How to write this?
```

such that the dynamic result is equivalent to:

```
type reducedType = {user: string;}
```

We also have access to an actual *reducer* instance (of type *reducerType*), if it helps.

Comment: Have you got the definition for `Reducer<T>` type itself?

Comment: Yes, but I'm wondering if there is a generic way to get T for any generic objects which accept a type argument.

Answer (score 0):

Reducer is just a function which gets and returns state, and the state is its generic parameter. So we could simply use the option from TypeScript 2.8:

```
type reducedType = ReturnType<reducerType>;
```

Another way (more complicated, but also more generic) is to use not only a type, but a helper function with intermediate (unused) constant value:

```
function getReducerType<T>(reducer: Reducer<T>): T {
     // for linters not to argue; we can return anything, in fact, we need only the declaration
    return {} as any;
};
const reducedValue = getReducerType(reducer);
type reducedType = typeof reducedValue;
```